# Reload the store and grid after editing in extjs 6

Tags: javascript, extjs

How can I reload the store and grid after clicking the Update or Cancel button of the tree editor

```
....
plugins: [{
        ptype: 'rowediting',
        clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
        autoCancel: false,
        listeners: {
           afteredit : function (editor, context, eOpts ){

               alert('How reload store and grid')
           },
           canceledit : function ( editor, context, eOpts ){
               alert('How reload store and grid')
           }
       }
    }],
...
```

Created an example in [FIDDLE]:https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2mg8

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
context.store.reload();
```

Write this in you event handler

Comment: Thanks.Your answer helped me